# How to remotely (SSH) execute script that has environment variables as argument

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a script located on a remote server.  It's in the following directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh.
```

I can execute the script locally on the server with:

```
/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh computername $env1 $env2
```

How can I execute this script remotely with SSH?  The environment variables are stored in /etc/profile on the remote server.  I get the error **not enough arguments** when running the following command locally:

```
ssh remoteserver -C "sh /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh computername $env1 $env2"
```

**Update**

I also get this error when using

```
ssh remoteserver -C 'sh /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh computername $env1 $env2'
```

**Update 2**

I got it working after I sourced my environment variables:

```
ssh salt -C 'source /etc/profile && sh /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh computername $env1 $env2'
```

Comment: use single-quotes; the local shell expands variables inside double-quotes before ssh even runs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  use `'command'`, not `"command"`. Because `""` will expands `$` and `\` while `''` disables all expansions.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.